# How to Make Python Module yt-dlp ignore Private Videos When Downloading A Playlist

Tags: python, download, youtube, yt-dlp

I'm Downloading a Playlist which has some hidden Videos so python gives me DownloadError, I want to Download the Whole Playlist at once. Is there a fix for that.
I'm trying to see if I can make it ignore those hidden videos

My Code:

```
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzMXToX8KzqhKrURIhVTJMb0v-HeDM3gs'
ydl_opts = {'format': 'mp4'}
with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)
```

Error Given in Terminal:

```
Enter your URL: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzMXToX8KzqhKrURIhVTJMb0v-HeDM3gs
[youtube:tab] PLzMXToX8KzqhKrURIhVTJMb0v-HeDM3gs: Downloading webpage
WARNING: [youtube:tab] YouTube said: INFO - 8 unavailable videos are hidden
[youtube:tab] PLzMXToX8KzqhKrURIhVTJMb0v-HeDM3gs: Downloading API JSON with unavailable videos
WARNING: [youtube:tab] YouTube said: INFO - Unavailable videos will be hidden during playback
[download] Downloading playlist: English Grammar
[youtube:tab] playlist English Grammar: Downloading 52 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 52
[youtube] JGXK_99nc5s: Downloading webpage
[youtube] JGXK_99nc5s: Downloading android player API JSON
ERROR: [youtube] JGXK_99nc5s: Private video. Sign in if you've been granted access to this video
```

Comment: You can use the `--ignore-errors` or `--no-abort-on-error` flag. See: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/a1ddaa899ca8693f31f34770f7263ace7e8c8841/README.md#general-options

Comment: where do i add it?? this code is run in VS code

Comment: Scroll up on that page; it says that in the command line, you can run `yt-dlp`, and pass that flag to the command, along with the playlist URL of course. If you want to do it from a Python script, which wouldn't be necessary if you just want to do this one time, then I'm not sure how you'd pass that flag, but there's got to be a way.

Comment: Actually, on that same Readme, it explains how to pass options to the `YoutubeDL` object. Here is an example of options being passed: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#extract-audio Except in your case you'd use the `ignoreerrors` option which is defined [here](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/master/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py#L181).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the documentation, I *think* this will do what you want - unfortunately I cannot test it at the moment, so let me know if it doesn't work:

```
import yt_dlp

ydl_opts = {
    'ignoreerrors': True
}

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzMXToX8KzqhKrURIhVTJMb0v-HeDM3gs'
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    error_code = ydl.download(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Indeed you use `'ignoreerrors': True`. and you can pass this directly to `YoutubeDl`.

```
with YoutubeDL(
        {'quiet': True, "logger": CustomLogger(), 'ignoreerrors': True}
    ) as temp:
    info_temp = temp.extract_info(link, download=False)
```

- The other options I have used are up to you.
- quiet - just hides the details on the console.
- `CustomLogger()` is a custom logger i have implemented so that it doesn't print the log on the console but to a file.
- 
- `download=False` is so that it doesn't download immediately. I have implemented the download elsewhere. My script can download and as well just get information about a video or playlist without downloading it.
- when we use `YoutubeDl` we are creating a `yt_dlp.YoutubeDL.YoutubeDL` object which then can be used to get various details from youtube links. so `temp` then is that object.

what is important is `ignoreerror`. `YoutubeDl` is right where the program starts. so we usually have a dictionary called `yt_opts` where we specify key-value pairs that will be passed to `YoutubeDL`. so you can pass them directly.

or better yet you can indeed create this `yt_opts` dictionary. so we would do:

```
link = "https://youtu.be/SaC8X-IHGiU?si=rkAN-ICgDk-7b2Em"
yt_opts({'ignoreerrors: True})

with YoutubeDL(yt_opts) as temp:
    info_temp = temp.extractinfo(link, download=False)
    # do more with info_temp eg `info_temp.get('title')` etc
```